# Can I become a Dutch citizen through my grandparents who were both born in The Netherlands

Tags: citizenship, netherlands, passport, dutch-citizens

Both my mother's parents as well as my father's mother were born in the Netherlands. Both my mother (1974) and my father (1969) were born in South Africa as well as myself (2000).

All other family history goes back to the Netherlands.

My grandparents immigrated to SA after WW2. My grandfather was a minor when he gave up his Dutch nationality. Both grandmothers gave it up after 21 and both parents were born after my grandparents naturalized. My mother's youngest sister was able to get her Dutch passport as she applied before a specific age (rule at that time). All the other siblings were too late.

Is there any way I can obtain a Dutch passport through my grandparents?

Comment: Related: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/15490/do-i-qualify-for-a-dutch-passport-if-my-mothers-parents-were-dutch-born-citizens?rq=1

Comment: What do you mean by "gave up"?  I don't think a minor can give up Dutch nationality.  They can lose it under certain circumstances through various acts of their parents.  When did your aunt get her Dutch passport?  How old was she at the time?